# Reconnect strategy in File inbound endpoint?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Do we have a "reconnect strategy" in File inbound endpoint? I don't think as it has only on the FTP connector. But the article screen showed that it's available.

https://dzone.com/articles/mulesoft-file-connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mule 4, it does. You need to configure yourself. Both the link you shared and official documentation says you can configure reconnection strategy for file connector: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/file/file-documentation#Reconnection

As far as I know, all connectors are derived from the same interface and support reconnection if applicable.

I recommend you to depend on the official documentation for these cases.

For mule 3, you should look into "File Transport" which is based on polling: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/file-transport-reference

It doesn't support reconnection and if you look at the source code, you'll also see that `doConnect` is not implemented since it is poll based: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/5ed22e1e60f584ea8f301ae5ffb16e5c0c5e25c1/transports/file/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/file/FileConnector.java#L299

Comment: Emin -  Yes, I am aware that it's available in Mule-4.x.  Any idea from the Mule-3.x perspective?

Comment: @NGBeginner updated my answer based on your comment